# Deleting from Rails Admin list without deleting them from actual blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I apologize if this has already been asked but I've looked all over stackoverflow and googled it as well.

I'm in the process of creating a rails application that takes the "simple blog" concept from most rails tutorials and adds an admin panel that decides whether posts submitted actually get posted to the main site. The issue I'm running into is that there are hundreds of posts and they all show up in the admin panel. All of the options to remove them from the panel also remove them from the site.

Is it possible to delete the blog posts on the admin site as they're published without deleting them from the main site or is it better to just keep them up? I'd imagine this would cause speed issues once there are thousands of them.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in your problem:

> Note: Add an extra field as "status" in the posts table where you are
>   storing posts actually.

1. From my blog a post is created and let us suppose its status is "Pending".
2. In my admin I only show posts with having status as "pending"
3. Now from admin panel when I am click a button like "approv" then I will change status of the post from "Pending" to "Published"
4. Thats all, your problem is solved

   - posts not deleted
   - Dont have much crowd of posts

Answer (score 0):

Usually RailsAdmin displays all the records of a model using its default scope. What you could do:

Create a Model, say `UnpublishedBlog`

```
class UnpublishedBlog < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.set_table_name "articles"

  default_scope where(:published => false)

  def destroy
    update_attribute(:published, true)
  end
end
```

So it will load all unpublished blogs, when you delete any it will be just published and eventually removed from the unpublished list.

If you dont want to see the original `Blog` model in `RailsAdmin` just exclude that from settings.